# using varnish for load balancing

Tags: varnish

i write a varnish vcl rules for my server and i don't know this is sufficient for my intent. i want run my project on 2 ports of server and on another server such that if one server gone down ,requests forward to other server. moreover i want to serve static files such that don't working apache web server and request for them directly sent to tornado. this is my vcl rules , can u help me ?

```
import directors;

probe healthcheck {
   .url = "/";
   .interval = 30s;
   .timeout = 1 s;
   .window = 5;
   .threshold = 2;
   .initial = 2;
   .expected_response = 200;
}

backend server1{
    .host="127.0.0.1"
    .port = 8004
     .probe = healtcheck;
} 
backend server1-2{
    .host="127.0.0.1"
    .port = 8005
     .probe = healtcheck;
} 
backend server2{
    .host="192.168.1.1"
    .port = 8004
     .probe = healtcheck;
} 
sub vcl_init {
    new vdir = directors.round_robin();
    vdir.add_backend(server1);
    vdir.add_backend(server1-2);
    vdir.add_backend(server2);
}

 sub vcl_recv{
set req.grace = 600s;



### always cache these items:

     if (req.request == "GET" && req.url ~ "\.(js)") {
                lookup;
        }

    ## images
        if (req.request == "GET" && req.url ~ "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|png|tiff|tif|ico|img|tga|wmf)$") {
        lookup;
        }

    ## various other content pages  
    if (req.request == "GET" && req.url ~ "\.(css|html)$") {    
        lookup;
        }       

    ## multimedia 
        if (req.request == "GET" && req.url ~ "\.(svg|swf|ico|mp3|mp4|m4a|ogg|mov|avi|wmv)$") {
        lookup;
        }   

    ## xml

        if (req.request == "GET" && req.url ~ "\.(xml)$") {
        lookup;
        }
### do not cache these rules:

        if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
                pipe;
        }
### if it passes all these tests, do a lookup anyway;
        lookup;

 }

sub vcl_fetch {

  if (req.url ~ "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|swf|css|js|flv|mp3|mp4|pdf|ico|png)(\?.*|)$") {
    set beresp.ttl = 365d;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if you require sessions to work for users you should switch from round_robin to hash. This will ensure the same users will be directed to the same backend.